# SQL Server: add a column and get other column names as its value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is a sample table

```
    DECLARE @t TABLE(a INT,b INT,c INT);
    INSERT @t VALUES(1,2,3),(9,8,7),(4,6,5);
    SELECT *
    ,      (   SELECT  MAX(val) 
               FROM    (VALUES (a)
                   ,   (b)
                   ,   (c)
               ) AS value(val)
           ) AS MaxVal 
    FROM @t;
```

Result:

```
A   B   C   MAX
---------------
1   2   3   3
9   8   7   9
4   6   5   6
```

I would like to add a column `Max_cols` which will have other column names as its values. column names are respective to the values that column 'MAX' has in it ...(hope this makes sense).

The result should look like this.

```
A   B   C   MAX   Max_cols
--------------------------
1   2   3     3       C
9   8   7     9       A
4   6   5     6       B
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this dynamically (at least not with table variables); one solution would be a `CASE` expression that explicitly lists each potential column name. You haven't explained how you want to handle ties, though...

```
;WITH x AS (SELECT *,
 (
   SELECT  MAX(val) 
   FROM    (VALUES (a)
           ,   (b)
           ,   (c)
           ) AS value(val)
    ) AS MaxVal 
    FROM @t
 ) SELECT *, Max_cols = CASE MaxVal 
 WHEN a THEN 'A' WHEN b THEN 'B' WHEN c THEN 'C' END
 FROM x;
```

Comment: this works for me... thank you. i didn't get what you meant by 'handle ties'!!

Comment: @sqlsean I meant what if the first row were 1,3,3? Do you want B or C?